# Каскадные циклы в базе данных

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Вот схема моей БД:
[image: Схема]

Столкнулся вот с такой ошибкой:
[image: Ошибка]

Мое предположение что здесь ошибка в том, что при удалении секции удаляются и группы и тренера, а при удалении тренера так же должны удалятся группы. Кто-нибудь объясните пожалуйста. Использую C# и EntityFramework. СУБД - SqlServer.

Comment: На вскидку: БД нужно перепроектировать, уже как минимум таблица "абонемент-клиент" включает в себя ещё и группы, тренеров, секции и залы - так точно не должно быть.

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin тут имеется ввиду что Абонемент - это какой либо вид абонемента (типо разовый, месячный и т.д.). А абонемент клиент это уже конкретный документ, закрепленный за клиентом, у который имеет определенный вид, которого тренирует определенный тренер, в такой то секции и в таком то зале. Можете пожалуйста конкретнее описать проблему проектировки, хотя бы в моменте, который вы обозначили. Просто в проектировании БД я новичок. Спасибо большое за комментарий)

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin посмотрите пожалуйста комментарий и новую схему

Answer (score 0):

Исправил путем удаления связей, образующих цикл. Так же некоторые связи сделал необязательными (стрелки указывают на слабые сущности, если стрелки нет, связь необязательна). Вот какая схема получилась, если что, жду комментарии!!!
[image: Схема]